# Are there theorems from electromagnetism that are a consequence of $C$, $P$ or $T$ invariance?

Tags: electromagnetism, cpt-symmetry

It's well known that classical electrodynamics is  $C$, $P$ and $T$ invariant. For example, see this question [Maxwell's equations and  $C$, $P$, $T$ Symmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98327/). Are there theorems within CED that are a consequence of any of these symmetries?

Comment: This is probably a list-based question, but maybe look into Helmholtz reciprocity.